# Length of array inside a jsonb with Postgres and Typeorm

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm, jsonb

I'm developing an app with NodeJS, PostgreSQL and Typeorm. I have a column "data" in my database which is of type jsonb. Each element has the following structure:

```
{
  "a": [
    { "b": "some-text" },
    { "b": "some-text" },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I want to select all rows where the size of the "a" array is N AND where the "b" field of the first object inside the array is of value X.

So far I tried to get the size query working first by using `jsonb_array_length` as follows:

```
await this.createQueryBuilder('entity')
        .where(`jsonb_array_length("entity".data->>'a') = 5`)
        .getMany();
```

However, this throws an error:

`No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use `->` operator to get josnb instead of `->>` which yields text. `jsonb_array_length("entity".data->'a') = 5`. BTW why don't you try native queries instead of the smudgy query builder?

Comment: @Stefanov.sm - You should reply as the answer, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `->` operator to get josnb instead of `->>` which yields text.
Your `where` expression should be this:

```sql
jsonb_array_length("entity".data -> 'a') = 5
```